# Capitalize specific indices of string using awk or python

Tags: python, loops, awk, capitalize

I have an input file where each line contains 99 lowercase letters,

```
bccdddcdccddddddabcdabcabdbacbdcaaccbbcabacbccabcacbcdcccbdbacdcbbcbcbcccacadaaccababadbcbaabbbccbb 
bccdddcdcddddcddabcdabcabdbacbddaacdbbcabacbcdbbcacbcccccbdbacdbbbcbcbacbacacaacccbabadbcbaabbbccbb 
bccdddcdcddddccdabcdabcabdbacbddaaddbbcabacbcdbbcacbcccccbdbacdbbbcbcbaccacadaaccbbabadbccacbbbccbb 
bccdddcdccdddccdabcdabcdbdbacbdcaaddcbcabacbccabcacbcdcccbdbacdbbbcbcbbccacadaaccbbabadbccaaabbccbb
```

I have a list of positions, for example `p = [10, 14, 89, 99]`.

I'd like to capitalize the letters at these positions in my input file.

Desired output:

```
bccdddcdcCdddDddabcdabcabdbacbdcaaccbbcabacbccabcacbcdcccbdbacdcbbcbcbcccacadaaccababadbCbaabbbccbB 
bccdddcdcDdddCddabcdabcabdbacbddaacdbbcabacbcdbbcacbcccccbdbacdbbbcbcbacbacacaacccbabadbCbaabbccbB 
bccdddcdcDdddCcdabcdabcabdbacbddaaddbbcabacbcdbbcacbcccccbdbacdbbbcbcbaccacadaaccbbabadbCcacbbccbbB 
bccdddcdcCdddCcdabcdabcdbdbacbdcaaddcbcabacbccabcacbcdcccbdbacdbbbcbcbbccacadaaccbbabadbCcaaabbccbB
```

I'm using this awk command:

```
awk -vFS= -vOFS= '{$10=toupper($10)}1' input > output
```

But I'm not sure how to loop this over all the positions.

Comment: Setting FS to null is undefined behavior per POSIX so YMMV with whatever that does in whatever awk you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a generator expression with `.upper()` and `enumerate()` to capitalize only the specified indices:

```py
p = [10, 14, 89, 99] # or use set([10, 14, 89, 99]) for faster lookup
with open('in.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        line = line.rstrip()
        result = ''.join(c.upper() if i + 1 in p else c for i, c in enumerate(line))
        print(result)
```

This outputs:

```
bccdddcdcCdddDddabcdabcabdbacbdcaaccbbcabacbccabcacbcdcccbdbacdcbbcbcbcccacadaaccababadbCbaabbbccbB
bccdddcdcDdddCddabcdabcabdbacbddaacdbbcabacbcdbbcacbcccccbdbacdbbbcbcbacbacacaacccbabadbCbaabbbccbB
bccdddcdcDdddCcdabcdabcabdbacbddaaddbbcabacbcdbbcacbcccccbdbacdbbbcbcbaccacadaaccbbabadbCcacbbbccbB
bccdddcdcCdddCcdabcdabcdbdbacbdcaaddcbcabacbccabcacbcdcccbdbacdbbbcbcbbccacadaaccbbabadbCcaaabbccbB
```

Comment: Or `enumerate(line, 1)`.

Answer (score 2):

One `awk` idea:

```
awk -v p="10,14,89,99" '
BEGIN { split(p,arr,",") }
      { for (i in arr)
            $0=substr($0,1,arr[i]-1) toupper(substr($0,arr[i],1)) substr($0,arr[i]+1)
        print
      }
' input
```

This generates:

```
bccdddcdcCdddDddabcdabcabdbacbdcaaccbbcabacbccabcacbcdcccbdbacdcbbcbcbcccacadaaccababadbCbaabbbccbB
bccdddcdcDdddCddabcdabcabdbacbddaacdbbcabacbcdbbcacbcccccbdbacdbbbcbcbacbacacaacccbabadbCbaabbbccbB
bccdddcdcDdddCcdabcdabcabdbacbddaaddbbcabacbcdbbcacbcccccbdbacdbbbcbcbaccacadaaccbbabadbCcacbbbccbB
bccdddcdcCdddCcdabcdabcdbdbacbdcaaddcbcabacbccabcacbcdcccbdbacdbbbcbcbbccacadaaccbbabadbCcaaabbccbB
```

Answer (score 2):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
bccdddcdccddddddabcdabcabdbacbdcaaccbbcabacbccabcacbcdcccbdbacdcbbcbcbcccacadaaccababadbcbaabbbccbb 
bccdddcdcddddcddabcdabcabdbacbddaacdbbcabacbcdbbcacbcccccbdbacdbbbcbcbacbacacaacccbabadbcbaabbbccbb 
bccdddcdcddddccdabcdabcabdbacbddaaddbbcabacbcdbbcacbcccccbdbacdbbbcbcbaccacadaaccbbabadbccacbbbccbb 
bccdddcdccdddccdabcdabcdbdbacbdcaaddcbcabacbccabcacbcdcccbdbacdbbbcbcbbccacadaaccbbabadbccaaabbccbb
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FPAT=".";OFS="";arr[10];arr[14];arr[89];arr[99]}{for(i in arr){$i=toupper($i)};print}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
bccdddcdcCdddDddabcdabcabdbacbdcaaccbbcabacbccabcacbcdcccbdbacdcbbcbcbcccacadaaccababadbCbaabbbccbB 
bccdddcdcDdddCddabcdabcabdbacbddaacdbbcabacbcdbbcacbcccccbdbacdbbbcbcbacbacacaacccbabadbCbaabbbccbB 
bccdddcdcDdddCcdabcdabcabdbacbddaaddbbcabacbcdbbcacbcccccbdbacdbbbcbcbaccacadaaccbbabadbCcacbbbccbB 
bccdddcdcCdddCcdabcdabcdbdbacbdcaaddcbcabacbccabcacbcdcccbdbacdbbbcbcbbccacadaaccbbabadbCcaaabbccbB
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that field is any single character using `FPAT` and field separator is empty string then I mention keys of array `arr` without caring about values as I will use only keys. For every line I iterate over keys of said array and apply tuupper to these position then I `print` line.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk` solution using `FIELDWIDTHS` option of GNU `awk`. Written and tested with ONLY shown samples.

```
awk -v FIELDWIDTHS="9 1 3 1 74 1 9 1" -v OFS="" '
function toUppeR(value){
  $value=toupper($value)
}
{
  for(i=2;i<=8;i+=2){
    toUppeR(i)
  }
}
1
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, using `FIELDWIDTHS` option of GNU `awk` by which we can define width of fields(so in given example we need to capitalize letters of `10, 14, 89, 99` positions, so I have made fields of to catch 10th position(9 ***1***) to catch 14th position(9 1 3 ***1***), to catch 89th position (9 1 3 1 74 ***1***) and so on... you can clearly see its easy to catch fields by position here though it can do some problem with `OFS`(output field separator) thing but that is NOT applicable at least for your shown samples.